# Preg_match for password always errors

Tags: php, passwords, preg-match

I'm using this for a password that needs to be 8-20 chars long, only numbers, letters and !@#$% symbols:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8, 20}$/', $_POST['password'])) {
    $errors[] = true;
    $_SESSION['error'] .= '<div class="messages status_red">Password must be 8-20 long, A-Z, 0-9, !@#$% only.</div>';   
}
```

However no matter if I meet the criteria or not I still return an error.

I don't see any error_reporting messages either.

Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: "only numbers, letters and !@#$%" --- that's a *stupid* limitation. Don't limit users on what characters they want to use in their passwords

Comment: You need to escape the `$`... [A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#\$%]

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: nope, `$` in a character set shouldn't be escaped

Comment: @zerkms I stand corrected, leaving comment for future reference

Comment: Why do you want to limit the set of characters?  Instead of "nothing but letters, numbers, and punctuation", it eems like it would be more useful to require "at least one letter, one number, and one punctuation mark" or similar.

Comment: i hate it when i'm not allowed to use my common passwords. if i am dumb enough to use a normal word then i deserve what i get. You better provide a forgot password option cause I would have to use it every single time I went to your site. I know I'm not alone on that too.

Comment: @zerkms What do you suggest it be then?

Comment: @MarkReed How would you do it?

Comment: @dragonfeet2012: I suggest it to be **any** character. Literally any, including non-printable (why not?)

Comment: See my edited answer below, @dragonfeet2012.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys.  I switched it to make it easier for users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put a space in `{8, 20}`. It should just be `{8,20}`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the space in `{8, 20}`, which keeps it from being recognized as a `{`*min*`,`*max*`}` quantifier.  But I don't know why you're complicating things with positive lookahead etc; something as simple as this should do the trick:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%]{8,20}$/',  $_POST['password'])
```

**EDITED TO ADD:** It would be better security practice to allow any character at all in the password.  If they can type it, let them use it - and it's on you to be able to process it without running afoul of SQL injection or similar. (You don't store passwords in your database anyway, right?  Right.)

If you want to require a certain amount of character diversity in order to encourage stronger passwords - for instance, require at least one each of letter, number, and neither - then you can do something like this.  Here, the use of lookahead means the letter, number, and neither-of-the-above can occur in any order in the password:

```
preg_match('/(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])/', $_POST['password'])
```

You could try to get the length requirements into the regex, too, but I would just check the length separately - and here again, I would have a minimum, but no maximum.  (Since passwords should never be stored, but only checksummed, longer passwords shouldn't incur any additional storage overhead.  But if you do run into a situation where you need to limit the length for some reason, try to pick a limit in the hundreds-of-characters range rather than the tens-of-characters range.)